# How to call function with dynamic parameter input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to call a function with dynamic parameter input, I am not sure if it is possible, any suggestion is welcome.

The scenario is like below:

I have a function with 5 parameters like this

`function(p1=v1, p2=v2, p3=v3, p4=v4,p5=v5)`

`v1-v5` are saved in an excel file and can be empty, if the value for a parameter is none(nothing entered in the excel), the parameter should not appear when call the function.

For example, if `v2=None`, when I call the function, it will look like `function(p1=v1, p3=v3, p4=v4,p5=v5)`.

Is it possible by checking the value of each parameter that I can call the function dynamically with parameters that have meaningful value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can do it like this;

When you declare your function you can set a default value and handle that case

```
def myFunction(p1=None, p2=None):
   // do some work and check if values exist
```

Then call your function like below:

```
result = myFunction(p1=v1)
```

Notice how we do not have to enter a value for p2. If no value is declared the default value of None will be set.

---

As an aside depending on your data/usecase you might also want to consider using a different data structure like an array/list

```
def myFunction(myList):
    // loop through myList and do something with the data
```

```
aList = [v1,v3,v4,v5]
result = myFunction(aList)
```